# Algorithm to group strings from list of lists

Tags: string, algorithm

I have several objects, each containing a list of strings.

```
Object 1
["one", "two", "three", "four"]
Object 2
["one", "two", "five", "seven", "eight"]
Object 3
["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "seven"]
Object 4
["one", "two", "nine", "ten"]
```

As you can see, the strings are repeated, and my task is to group these strings and refer these groups in the objects instead of the strings themselves. The output should look like:

```
group1
["one", "two"]
group2
["three", "four"]
group3
["five", "seven"]
group4
["eight"]
group5
["nine", "ten"]
```

And the object would contain reference to the groups instead

```
Object 1
["group1", "group2"]
Object 2
["group1", "group3", "group4"]
Object 3
["group1", "group2", "group3"]
Object 4
["group1", "group5"]
```

Thankfully, this grouping is over a static set of data and each object consists of around 20 such strings.

It doesn't matter if a string appears in two groups, but that is a nice to have, so, unless it is ridiculously easy to create such groups, that is not an objective at this point.

I've simplified my problem using strings as example, but in my document, they are JSON objects that are repeated over and over. The objective to group them and refer those groups instead so that the same object is not repeated again and again. So, to say, the goal is reduce repetition.

<s>I understand this is some sort of [clustering problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis), but I am unable to formalize these strings into points in (x,y) plane.</s>
How do I approach this? Is there a name for this problem?

Edit: After some thinking, I think I should find the disjoint set of strings in all these lists and work from there. Union find algorithm seems like a good fit.

Comment: How is the grouping done? What grouping criteria do you use?

Comment: There are no rules to the grouping. Any strings can be grouped, but the objective is to avoid repeating a bunch of strings, but instead refer to their group. Say, if I have these 7 strings repeating in 4 objects, instead of writing 28 strings, I would mention the one group in the 4 objects. @user3437460

Comment: I would say that cluster analysis is not what you need here as it is mainly a statistical approach for defining categories in n-dimensional space. You are dealing with clearly defined groups (it seems) and not answering questions regarding distance or best group definition

Comment: @LucasKot-Zaniewski You are right. Cluster analysis does not fit this problem. I'm thinking in terms of disjoint sets, sort of divide and conquer.

Comment: I see that groups can be of different lengths...can a string ever be in two different groups? If so would you want the flexibility to merge the two groups (with the shared element) into one group? From my understanding the disjoint set data structure creates groups based on node-vertex relationships. You seem to already have the groups defined..

Comment: @LucasKot-Zaniewski Yes, the groups can be different lengths and a string can be in different groups. Perhaps I can decide on the flexibility later, but for now, my focus is to find a working solution and then adjust for other things.

Comment: so let's say you have group1: ["one", "two"] and group2 ["two", "three"]. Then have object1: ["one", "two", "three"] .. how do you plan to reconcile this? I also want to add that there is not algorithmic "hack" to do this from how you have explained your problem. Disjoint sets are not going to help you as they answer different questions altogether. The sets also need to be disjoint, which goes against your description of your groups.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to find subsequences in common from every subset of your list of objects.  This is similar to a compression algorithm; but with strings rather than characters.

A generalized solution sounds like it would be intractable for dozens of objects each consisting of dozens of strings.  The number of possible subsequences for each object is on the order of !n (log(n) factorial) (every bit pattern with a single contiguous sequence of ones) and the number of subsets of objects is 2**n.

Comment: @Jim Dennis I know it's hard to speculate but doesn't it look from the examples that OP is trying to find an exact ordered sub-sequence to sequence match, specifically matching any [c<sub>n</sub>,..,c<sub>n+m</sub>] of some [c<sub>0</sub>,..,c<sub>j</sub>] to be exactly equal to a set [f<sub>0</sub>,..,f<sub>m</sub>]. If we bound m to a constant (as OP has done in examples) then matching one list against the other would be done in quadratic time.

Comment: @LucasKot-Zaniewski: I agree.  If we're willing just search for bounded lists of sequences ... for instance 5, 4, 3, 2 with longest wins ... then the problem becomes tractable.

Comment: @LucasKot-Zaniewski Exactly, having the same string in two groups will make the whole exercise a lot more confusing, so, as stated in the question, I would avoid. Either way, thanks for your inputs, I will rework the question.

Comment: @LucasKot-Zaniewski Thank you very much. I'm a bit embarrassed to admit that I ended up sorting them into lists manually and now they are all grouped well. At the time I posted this question, it sounded like a good idea to arrive at a solution by analysis. However, it is an interesting problem to solve, so, I will check your answer some time soon.

Answer (score 1):

I perform a very similar calculation in one of my programs for `$JOB` and so long as I keep it generic, it's safe to share.

I'm going to write this in python3, and I'm translating it from a very different language, so there may be slip-ups and there are definitely spots where you can find an obvious speed improvement:

```
def findGroups(llStrs):
  # Input should be a list of lists of strings
  all_things = frozenset.union(frozenset(), *(map(frozenset, llStrs)))
  all_singletons = frozenset.union(frozenset(), *(frozenset(x) for x in llStrs if len(x) == 1))
  working = [all_things - all_singletons]
  for lStr in llStrs:
    setLStr = frozenset(lStr)
    working2 = []
    for w in working:
      if (w & setLStr) and not (w <= setLStr):
        a = w & setLStr
        b = w - setLStr
        if len(a) > 1:
          working2.append(a)
        if len(b) > 1:
          working2.append(b)
      else:
        working2.append(w)
    working = working2
  final_working_union = frozenset.union(*working)
  return working + [frozenset({x}) for x in (all_things - final_working_union)]
```

Now, this might not be absolutely what you want - each group is disjoint, and it might be that for your use it'd be better if sometimes groups overlapped. However, that's roughly the way I group things in my project.

Comment: Thanks for the pseudo code. I use python too, so, I will try to get this script working and understand what it is doing.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example in Python. We define a group class to carry a list and an alias. Then we loop over the list of the Object we want to compress until no more replacements are possible. Note that I sort the group list so that the longer matches get precedence over shorter matches.

The union-find algorithm won't help you here as it is used to see if two nodes are in the same set when taking a graph (parent-child mappings) as an input and then merging the two sets if they are not. You could find more time-efficient ways of telling if *two* elements are members of the same set (such as a dictionary keyed off by individual element with a pointer to the group it is in, essentially what a flattened disjoint set looks like) but I don't see how this would help you in the problem you described. You don't have the right input nor do you require the achieved output of the mentioned algorithm so I don't see how it is of any use to you in this case.

What you are describing is matching an ordered subset
[c<sub>n</sub>,..,c<sub>n+m</sub>] of some set [c<sub>0</sub>,..,c<sub>j</sub>] to be exactly equal to an *already defined* group [f<sub>0</sub>,..,f<sub>m</sub>] (the compression won't be very effective if we can group at most two elements which is why we have generalized the group length to `m`). There is no real gain here to using the disjoint-set structure as far as I can see.

Finally, if your goal is to minimize your memory footprint by picking optimal substitution groups of frequently repeating subsequences I recommend looking at the topic of data compression.

```
class group:
    def __init__(self,stringList, name):
        self.list = stringList
        self.alias = name

class object1:
    def __init__(self,stringList):
        self.list = stringList

g1 = group(["one", "two"], "group1")
g2 = group(["five", "seven"], "group2")
g3 = group(["seven"], "group3")
g4 = group(["three", "five", "seven"], "group4")
o = object1(["one", "two", "three", "five", "seven", "seven", "eight", "nine"])
group_list = [g1, g2, g3, g4]
group_list.sort(key=lambda x: len(x.list), reverse=True)

def match_elems(match_group, sub_list, index):
    for i in range(index, min(index + len(match_group.list), len(sub_list))):
        if match_group.list[i-index] != sub_list[i]:
            return False
    return True

def compress(obj, groups):
    for g in group_list:
        n = 0
        while n < len(obj.list):
            if match_elems(g, obj.list, n):
                obj.list = obj.list[:n] + [g.alias] + obj.list[n:]
                obj.list = obj.list[:n+1] + obj.list[n+len(g.list)+1:]
                print(obj.list)
            n=n+1

compress(o, group_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
p = ["one", "two", "three", "four"]

q = ["one", "two", "five", "seven", "eight"]

r = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "seven"]

s = ["one", "two", "nine", "ten"]

p, q, r, s = map(set, [p, q, r, s])
u = p | q | r | s
groups = {}
elements = [p, q, r, s]
index_map = {i:set() for i, _ in enumerate(elements)}
for i in u:
    count = 0
    current = []
    for k, j in enumerate(elements):
        if {i}.issubset(j):
            count += hash(count + 1 + k)
            current += [k]
    if not count in groups:
        groups[count] = [i]
    else:
        groups[count] += [i]
    for t in current:
        index_map[t] |= {count}
print groups
print index_map
```

Idea behind the code above is to check how many times an element repeats across different sets, based on that give that element a unique key in a dictionary. So every element which is there in all sets will fall under same key or element which is repeated in N number of sets will have unique key. once we have unique key we have to map original data with new data, to do that I'm going to keep track of element indexes which is having the current element in different sets. And finally I perform set union.